# In R, how can I insert a TRUE / FALSE column if strings in columns ARE / ARE NOT alphabetic?

Tags: regex, r, alphabetical

Sample data:
`df <- data.frame(noun1 = c("cat","dog"), noun2 = c("apple", "tree"))`

```
  noun1 noun2
1   cat apple
2   dog  tree
```

How can I make a new column `df$alpha` that would read `FALSE` in row 1 and `TRUE` in row 2?

Thank you!

Comment: what's the logical test?

Comment: For row 1, is "cat" then "apple" in alphabetical order? `FALSE`. For row 2, is "dog" then "tree" in alphabetical order? `TRUE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just apply `is.unsorted()` to each row, although you have to unlist it first (probably).

```
 df <- data.frame(noun1 = c("cat","dog"), noun2 = c("apple", "tree"))
 df$alpha <- apply(df,1,function(x) !is.unsorted(unlist(x)))
```

I found `is.unsorted()` via `apropos("sort")`.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of `is.unsorted()`. I'll accept your answer asap.